# httprequest call Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: xmlhttprequest, access-control

I'm trying to get some data from this imdb api: http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/#usage

However I'm getting errors using this code:

```
<hmtl>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  try { 
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try { 
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      xmlhttp = false; 
    }
  }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q=The+Green+Mile", false);
xmlhttp.send();

var imdbData = xmlhttp.responseText;
//var imdbJSON = eval("(" + imdbData + ")");
alert(imdbData);




</script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is this: Origin http://mysite.nl is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
test.html:23Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Could someone post a working code on this request? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access other server's data like you can your's. It violates the same origin policy. For cross domain requests you could use jQuery and JSONP, see:

- http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide
- http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

If you don't use jQuery you can google "cross domain ajax" or something. Maybe these links give you some ideas

- http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj
- http://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/feb13/

As for the working code request. Well, now that you are aware of the same origin policy, maybe you'll get it to work yourself...